# error getting div data using jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies, if-statement, conditional-statements

i'm having a hidden div with id "res" inside it i echo the user name if the cookie is set other wise it echo nouser

and i have this code in the head to check if a user exists to open a fancybox to buy a product other wise he'll be asked to register

```
$("a.add_to_cart").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var res = $("div#res").text();
    if (res == "nouser") {
        noty({
            "text": "you must login first",
            "layout": "center",
            "type": "error",
            "textAlign": "center",
            "easing": "swing",
            "animateOpen": {
                "height": "toggle"
            },
            "modal": "true",
            "animateClose": {
                "height": "toggle"
            },
            "speed": "500",
            "timeout": "2000",
            "closable": true,
            onClose: function () {},
            "closeOnSelfClick": true
        });
    } else {
        var pro_name = $(this).attr("pro_name");
        var pro_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var qst = "?pro=" + pro_id;
        var ajax = false;
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("get", "ajax/check_exists.php" + qst);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                var result = ajax.responseText;
                if (result == 'in cart') {

                    noty({
                        "text": "product already exists in the cart",
                        "layout": "center",
                        "type": "error",
                        "textAlign": "center",
                        "easing": "swing",
                        "animateOpen": {
                            "height": "toggle"
                        },
                        "modal": "true",
                        "animateClose": {
                            "height": "toggle"
                        },
                        "speed": "500",
                        "timeout": "2000",
                        "closable": true,
                        onClose: function () {},
                        "closeOnSelfClick": true
                    });


                } else {
                    $("a.add_to_cart[id=" + pro_id + "]").unbind("click");
                    var qst1 = "?pro=" + pro_id;
                    $("#proID").text(pro_id);
                    var ajax1 = false;
                    ajax1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    ajax1.open("get", "ajax/get_submit.php" + qst1);
                    ajax1.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (ajax1.readyState == 4 && ajax1.status == 200) {
                            $("#addDiv").html(ajax1.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                    ajax1.send(null);

                    $("a[id=" + pro_id + "]").fancybox({
                        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                            'transitionOut': 'elastic'
                    }).click();
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send(null);


    }

});
```

when i use firebug i find that the div contains : nouser but the fancybox keeps showing up what's wrong with the jquery if condition ?

Comment: make sure that the returned `result` is `in cart` not `in%20cart`

Comment: the first condition is not working the div contains nouser but the script goes on as there's no condition at all

Comment: that's a very simple example and it doesn't work too
     $("a.add_to_cart").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

   var res = $("div#res").text();
   alert(res);
   if(res == "nouser"){
    alert("there's no user") ;
   }
   else{
    alert("user exists"); 
   }
first time alert is : nouser then directly another alert : user exists it get's the right value but the if statement doesn't work and goes directly to else statement

Comment: try `res === "nouser"`

Comment: didn't work. the div contains "nouser" and the alert is "user exists"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any additional whitespaces in your `.text()` value?  maybe try trimming the value before the conditional `if(res.trim() == 'nouser')`

Comment: i have changed it to : if(res.indexOf('nouser')){
noty({"text":"login first","layout":"center","type":"error","textAlign":"center","easing":"swing","animateOpen":{"height":"toggle"},"modal":"true","animateClose":{"height":"toggle"},"speed":"500","timeout":"2000","closable":true,onClose:function(){},"closeOnSelfClick":true});
    }
    and still getting the login message even i'm logged it

Comment: don't use indexOf, it can return a 0 even if nouser is found... instead try `if(res.trim() == 'nouser')`